# How to start a process, get its pid, and kill it later?

Tags: c

Firstly, this is similar to questions asked before here and elsewhere, but I just can't get any of those answers to work. What I'm trying to build is a 'wrapper' around another program that starts it and returns the PID of the running process.

Later on, to reconfigure something, I have to 'kill -9 pid' said program (trust me, there's no other way, even 'kill pid' doesn't work), do the reconfiguring, restart otherprogram, and return the PID back upstream.

Nothing that I've tried from any other answer has come close to returning a pid, not system(), popen(), fork(), nothing in the exec_() family. All of them only return 0 or negative errors, nothing returns a pid. getpid() and getppid() don't help, they're only the pids of the calling program, not of the otherprogram I'm starting.

It also may have something to do with the fact that otherprogram includes an 'os_daemon()' line, that is, when it starts, it does stuff, and daemonises itself. NB that i can read the source of this otherprogram but I can't modify it.

Anyway, what i'm trying to do is something like this:

```
int startup() {
  int retval;
  /* do other stuff */
  retval = startsomehow("otherprogram args");
  return retval;
}

int reconfigure(int runningpid) {
  int retval;
  system("kill -9 %d",runningpid); /* this doesn't work as written, but you get the idea of what i'm trying to do */
  /* do other stuff */
  retval = startsomething("otherprogram args");
  return retval;
}
```

The closest I've come to anything working is something along the lines of:

```
system("otherprogram args");
retval = (int)system("ps aux | awk '/otherprogram/ {print $1}' | head -n 1"); //this doesn't correctly parse it into an int and still returns 0 because I'm not reading the output properly, but you get the idea
```

It's rather clunky but almost works, awk prints to the commandline but doesn't make it into the code as a properly formatted int, if I could get this bit working I'd accept it as a last-ditch effort but I'd prefer to have something that just returned a pid straight off without using system() too much.

Absolute absolute last-resort is to just ignore the pid side of things and issue a 'killall -9 otherprogram', but there's a chance that I may in future end up with 2 copies of the same program running with different pids, so I'd prefer the ability to just kill one and leave the other alone.

ps, this is what happens in a test file when I use fork():

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fprintf(stdout,"Start, I am pid = %d\n",getpid());

    int foo = (int)fork();
    fprintf(stdout,"Forked, pid = %d\n",foo);

    if (foo == 0) {
        fprintf(stdout,"This is child, my pid = %d\n",getpid());
        fprintf(stdout,"This is child, foo = %d\n",foo);
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout,"This is parent, my pid = %d\n",getpid());
        fprintf(stdout,"This is parent, foo = %d\n",foo);
        foo = exec("otherprogram","args"); //nb, redacted name
        fprintf(stdout,"exec returned = %d\n",foo);
        system("ps aux | tail -n 9");
    }
}
```

gives:

```
Start, I am pid = 367
Forked, pid = 368
This is parent, my pid = 367
This is parent, foo = 368
Forked, pid = 0
This is child, my pid = 368
This is child, foo = 0
  329 root     [kworker/0:0]
  354 root     [kworker/u2:0]
  366 root     [kworker/u2:2]
  367 root     ./testfoo
  368 root     [testfoo]
  370 nobody   otherprogram
  371 root     sh -c ps aux | tail -n 9
  372 root     ps aux
  373 root     tail -n 9
```

none of those results gives '370', which is the number I want

Comment: On Unix-like systems, `fork()` and `exec()` (unless you're into the agony of `posix_spawn()`).  The return from `fork()` in the parent tells you the PID of the child.  The child knows it is the child and executes the program you want to monitor.

Comment: Note than on an UNIX-ish system, a program with daemonizes itself runs as the grandchild of the process which was started by the shell (or, in your case, the "wrapper"). That's why daemons usually write their PID to some file -- it is quite difficult to get the PID of the running daemon from the PID of the transient process started by the shell (or "wrapper").

Comment: `exec()` does *not* change the PID. So if you `fork()` you know the PID of the child, which remains unchanged when the child `exec()`s the target program. The trouble is that you said that the program runs as a daemon; this mean that it will call `fork()` and die, its child will call `fork()` and die, and the *grandchild* is the actual running daemon.

Comment: @DrCroubie The `fork()` needs to be followed by an `exec()`. `exec()` doesn't change the PID.

Comment: Thanks, but i've tried that: fork() only returns the pid of the cloned process, but when that then starts my 'otherprogram', the pid of 'otherprogram' (which is what I want) is another different number again.

Comment: @DrCroubie *but when that then starts my 'otherprogram'* -- how do you start this after `fork()`

Comment: gah, comments don't like code, I'll edit original question with what happens when I use fork

Comment: Er, `exec` does not return unless it errors. Where is that `ps` output coming from?

Comment: Do note that you can kill by PGID rather than PID if you really have to.

Comment: Well exactly, exec() doesn't return anything. So how do I know what is the pid of the process that it created? That's what I'm asking, basically.

Comment: `exec()` does not change the PID. `exec()` does not create a process. All it does is replace the image which is executing in the context of the current process. But a *daemon* forks twice, so that you *cannot know* it's PID. You can *guess* by running `psgrep` or similar, or you can read it from the daemon's PID file if it is well-behaved and writes a PID file.

Comment: and I've just rechecked the code of 'otherprogram' where I said is daemonised itself using os_daemon(). I thought by looking at it that was a standard program but it turns out that it's (yet another) subroutine in (yet another) file included by 'otherprogram' (seriously, that thing is huge), and inside there it does indeed fork() itself. So now I take it that this is impossible to answer? Can anyone help me format my 'awk' line properly to get the pid into my program as an int that way?

Comment: Check `ps ax -o pid,ppid,pgrp,comm,cmd` output, and see if 'otherprogram' starts in a new session/process group. It it does not, have your child process do `setsid()` before `exec()` to start a new session and process group. Then you can kill the entire process group as needed using `kill(-child, SIGKILL)`. If you just want the PID of 'otherprogram', use either `pidof otherprogram` or `ps -C otherprogram -o pid=`. Note that `-C` matches to the `comm` field in most Linux systems.